# Define Terminology Within Document

Tags: amsmath, newtheorem, definition

Similar to the `\newtheorem*{dfn}{Definition}` statement, is there a way to define words in a document in this fashion, but instead of

**Definition.** *This is the definition*

being shown, it will show up as

**The Word.** *This is the definition*

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Unnumbered or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the header of the environment variable.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newcommand{\definedterm}{} % initialize
\newtheorem*{worddefinner}{\definedterm}
\newenvironment{worddef}[1]
 {\renewcommand{\definedterm}{#1}\begin{worddefinner}}
 {\end{worddefinner}}

\begin{document}

\begin{worddef}{Gnu}
A big animal.
\end{worddef}

\begin{worddef}{Gnat}
A tiny beast.
\end{worddef}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want automatic numbering, define a proper theorem style.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newcommand{\definedterm}{} % initialize
\newtheoremstyle{worddef}
  {\topsep}   % ABOVESPACE
  {\topsep}   % BELOWSPACE
  {\itshape}  % BODYFONT
  {0pt}       % INDENT (empty value is the same as 0pt)
  {\bfseries} % HEADFONT
  {.}         % HEADPUNCT
  {5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt} % HEADSPACE
  {(\thmnumber{#2})\thmname{ #1}} % CUSTOM-HEAD-SPEC
\theoremstyle{worddef}
\newtheorem{worddefinner}{\definedterm}
\newenvironment{worddef}[1]
 {\renewcommand{\definedterm}{#1}\begin{worddefinner}}
 {\end{worddefinner}}

\begin{document}

\begin{worddef}{Gnu}
A big animal.
\end{worddef}

\begin{worddef}{Gnat}
A tiny beast.
\end{worddef}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution. Instead of using `\newtheorem`, I can use the following:

```
\begin{description}
  \item[Word] Definition.
\end{description}
```

which outputs:

**Word.** *Definition.*

My question now is how do I number this list, so it may look like the following:

**(1) Word.** *Definition.*

**(2) Second Word.** *Definition.*